# ssh connection from linux via windows to server

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a linux computer and a windows computer which are connected to different networks.

- I would like to connect from my linux machine to a remote ssh server.
- From my linux computer I can access my windows computer, but I cannot access external ssh servers.
- From the windows computer I can access external ssh servers.

I there a way to connect from my linux to an external ssh server through my windows machine?

I tried to set up an ssh tunnel on my windows machine using Putty, but I didn't get it to work. If this would be a good way to solve my problem, could anyone help me with the settings? Otherwise, does anyone know of a better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: What application is running on the Windows machine that allows Linux to connect to it? Is it an SSH server?

Comment: @xofer I have control over that machine, so in theory I can mostly install what I need. I had understood that Putty could be used to connect *to* from Linux (for tunneling), but maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: I see -- I'm no Windows expert, but you'll need to run an SSH server in order to tunnel with SSH. AFAIK, PuTTY is a client only.

Answer (score 0):

Try CopSSH, it is full-featured OpenSSH for Windows.

You can either go with the latest build - https://www.itefix.net/copssh
Or you can try to look for its version 3.1.4, which is famous for being last completely free release.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use cygwin's OpenSSH server to do what you are asking using the steps on [this page](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~smp/projects/ssh-windows/). It worked well enough that I can now SSH into my Windows box using my domain credentials and get a Windows or Cygwin command prompt (depending on what my shell settings are in my Cygwin /etc/passwd file. I have also been able to use X forwarding this way from my Windows box.